# auto-optimize data in apache solr 5.4.1

Tags: apache, optimization, indexing, solr

I am indexing over than 1500000 of items from Mysql with Apache Solr 5.4.1, and when I enter to the Solr Admin Page everyday, I found that there is over than 5000 deleted items that they should be optimized, then I click to Optimze and all will be okay.

Is there a simple url to put it in the Crontab to Automate the Optimization of the indexes in Apache Solr 5.4.1 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example from UpdateXMLMessages](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22optimize.22):

> This example will cause the index to be optimized down to at most 10
>   segments, but won't wait around until it's done (waitFlush=false):
>
> curl
>   'http://localhost:8983/solr/core/update?optimize=true&maxSegments=10&waitFlush=false'

.. but in general, you don't have to optimize very often. It might not be worth the time spent doing the actual optimize and the extra disk activity. If you're re-indexing the index completely each time as well, indexing to a fresh collection and then swapping the collections afterwards is also a possible solution.